# Time complexity of the python3 code below:

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, time-complexity

```
if val in my_list:
    return my_list.index(val)
```

'in' operator has an average complexity of O(n). index() has a complexity of O(n) at worst case. Then is the complexity of these two lines of code exponential i.e. O(n^2) ? or O(n) ?

Comment: `List` is a type, not an instantiated object, so `List` will not have values that `val` could be in.

Comment: `List` could very well be an instance of a list. That would be poor practice, but completely legal.

Comment: Yes, it *could*, in that it would compile (probably). But.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that `List` is replaced with a valid variable name, it should be O(n) (as Nathaniel mentioned). The `in` operation runs on average n/2 times and in some cases the `index` operation runs again on average n/2 times. -> O(n) + O(n) = O(n)

Why don't you use a for loop over the indexes themselves?

Comment: I don't think that's correct? Even if `List` is a variable holding a list (and not the Python type `List`), `if val in` should be `O(n)` and at worst `index()` is `O(n)`, meaning this would be `O(2n) -> O(n)`.

Comment: @NathanielFord Yes you are right, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you have two `O(n)` operations, it will only become `O(n^2)` if the latter operation happens *each time* the former operation runs. In this case, the `if` is a branch - either you go down the `True` evaluation branch or the `False` evaluation branch.

Therefore, you have either:

```
if val in my_list -> evaluates to false, takes O(n) to check each element
End, because there is nothing else to do here. Total of O(n).
```

Or

```
if val in my_list -> e evaluates to true, takes O(n) to check each element
my_list.index(val) -> find the index, takes O(n) to check each element
End. Total is O(n) plus O(n)
```

Compare this to:

```
for i in my_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("Index of even number is {}", my_list.index(i))
```

Here we are iterating through the list, and on each element we might re-iterate through the whole list. This would be `O(n^2)`. (Facilely; in actuality this is `O(n log n)` because we know that `index()` will never go past the current index. It's kind of hard to contrive an example where this actually reaches exponential using `index`.)